# How to Set Cookie in Object Structure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

How can I set cookie in my .Net,Mvc Application in Object Structure??

The cookie structure should be like this

[image]

In Classic asp the exact thing we can achieve in this way

```
Response.Cookies("Company")("ComNo") =12346
Response.Cookies("Company")("ComUsrAcc") =111194
```

Now I want to the exact thing in my .Net Mvc application.How can i do this??

Thanks

Comment: it's same in MVC

Comment: so silly!!!!!!!!!!!! 
@satsvelke Thanks a lot man !!!!!

Comment: But how can i set properties like Expires or Path ??

Comment: with "Expires " property